# How to replace colon in string variable even if it is in XML format?

Tags: java, xml

I transfer the result data to UI from XML using java.
I get the output in String value.
In this value,
I have span tag class contain fontfamily_result font_weight:bold,
because of this : colon, I can't create a CSS class.
How can I remove the colon from this String Value?

```
for (int x = 0; x < element.getLength(); x++)
        {
            Node e = element.item(x);
            if (e instanceof Element && !e.getNodeName().equals("exam") && !e.getNodeName().equals("result")){
                source = new DOMSource(e);
                transformer.transform(source, result);
                elementText = sw.toString();
                System.out.println("elementText_Result : :"+elementText);
            }
        }
```

I am getting xml value through elementText.
To replace the String value

```
elementText = elementText.replace(":","_")
```

output:
In span tag class contain colon and I need to change it as underscore.

```
<p class="exam_result" id="EX1921145_EXAM_RESULT"><span  class="fontfamily_result font_weight:bold ">Pass</span></p>
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what is the problem with `replace()`, could you reformulate your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elementText = elementText.replace(":","_")

This should work fine, I just checked and I can see its getting replace.

```
System.out.println("<p class=\"exam_result\" id=\"EX1921145_EXAM_RESULT\"><span  class=\"fontfamily_result font_weight:bold \">Pass</span></p>".replace(":", "_"));
```

Output:

```
<p class="exam_result" id="EX1921145_EXAM_RESULT"><span  class="fontfamily_result font_weight_bold">Pass</span></p>
```

Comment: How do you use the backslash "\" in between the String value...? I am not mention in my question.

Comment: How you are adding backslash before toublequate...?

Comment: Backslash is used to escape double quote in the String.